# Killing function in AJAX-requested content

Tags: jquery, kill

I have a slider, which is called with AJAX-modal. This works awesome, but if I close the modal, and open up a different modal with the same slider, it's obvious that the first function hasn't been killed, because it slides at the wrong intervals. After I open and close several modals, the slider is sliding uncontrollably, as if the event from the previous calls are still active, and is telling the slider to slide. I need to kill the slider when I close the overlay, so that it is not "active" when I call it again.

I have edited out code that I don't find relevant, but replaced it with comments to give you an idea of how it's put together.

**Function to call the AJAX**

```
$(".locationResultLink").click(function () {
  // The overlay is faded in,
  // and then the AJAX-content is loaded into it      

  // Variable url is pulled from a property on (this) 
  // + ID of box on AJAX-requested page

  $("#overlayInner").load(url, function () {
     // When load is successful, call the slider             
     $(this, '#ajaxSlider').Horinaja({
        capture: 'ajaxSlider', delay: 0.3,
        duration: 4, pagination: true
     });
  });
```

**Function to close the AJAX**

```
// The close button is actually on the AJAX-page, so we use on()    
$("body").on("click", "#btnOverlayClose", function () {
   // The overlay is faded out, and then ...
   $("#ajaxSlider").die();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be;

```
$(".locationResultLink").click(function () {
  var self = $(this);
  var dataKey = 'click-id';
  var clickId = (self.data(dataKey) || 0) + 1;

  self.data(dataKey, clickId);

  // The overlay is faded in,
  // and then the AJAX-content is loaded into it      

  // Variable url is pulled from a property on (this) 
  // + ID of box on AJAX-requested page

  $("#overlayInner").load(url, function () {
     if (self.data(dataKey) == clickId) {
       // When load is successful, call the slider             
       $(this, '#ajaxSlider').Horinaja({
          capture: 'ajaxSlider', delay: 0.3,
          duration: 4, pagination: true
       });
     }
  });
```

Or even;

```
(function () {

  var counter = 0;    

  $(".locationResultLink").click(function () {
    var id = ++counter;

    // The overlay is faded in,
    // and then the AJAX-content is loaded into it      

    // Variable url is pulled from a property on (this) 
    // + ID of box on AJAX-requested page

    $("#overlayInner").load(url, function () {
       if (counter == id) {
         // When load is successful, call the slider             
         $(this, '#ajaxSlider').Horinaja({
            capture: 'ajaxSlider', delay: 0.3,
            duration: 4, pagination: true
         });
       }
    });
  });

}());
```

What we do here is increment a counter each time, and check in the call back that the counter hasn't been incremented; if it hasn't, we initialize the slider, and if it has, we don't.

Another approach would be to use the `abort()` method on the [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), however you'd to use [a different ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) to `load()`, as load does not give you access to the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure this will work in my case, but I will give it a shot later, and let you know how it went.

Comment: Nope, sadly none of these functions seem to work for me. I am not sure why.

Mind, the sliders will probably have different content depending on which element is clicked, so I will need to load it and somehow kill it every time.

abort() does sound promising, but I haven't played with it before. I will read up on it and get back to you. :)